# How to align the source code block when export to PDF in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, pdflatex

While using org-mode to export source code to PDF files, the source code is not aligned with the indentation of the text.

The .org file are as follow:

[image]

And the output result looks like this:

[image]

Would there be a way to align the indentation of the code block, or make it centralized?

Thank you very much!

---

Adding the original org text

```
* STAT_Asump

** Table structrue

The following pre
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment BVerbatmi
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
CREATE TABLE STAT_Asump(
    PLANID      int4,
    PrdType     int4,
    Disc_Rate   float8,
    Loading     LD_Struct[],
    Dec_Rates   text[],
    Acc_Rates   text[],
    Benefit     Ben_Struct[],
    record      text NOT NULL,
    primary key(PlanID)
);
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: It would have been more helpful if one could copy the org text in order to try to replicate, rather than copy manually it from an image...

Comment: This is a LaTeX problem, so it has to be solved in LaTeX, Moreover I thought somebody has already replied with the solution. Did you cross post to Emacs SE and here? If so, that's a no-no: choose one place and ask the question (generally Emacs SE is the right place for Org mode questions).

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52763/how-to-align-the-source-code-block-when-export-to-pdf-in-org-mode where an answer has been posted.